# For loop date variable to SQL in python

Tags: python, sql, for-loop

I am writing a Oracle SQL query inside a Python script. The query is as follows:

```
query_dict={
    'df_fire':
    '''
    SELECT INSURED_ID AS CUST_ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    from POLICY
    WHERE POLICY_EXPDATE >= TO_DATE('2018/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
    AND POLICY_EFFDATE <= TO_DATE('2018/01/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
    GROUP BY INSURED_ID
    '''
}
"""

#Note: The duration for this kind of insurance policy is one-year.
#Note: It only shows each policy's effective date(POLICY_EFFDATE) and expire date(POLICY_EXPDAT) in the database.
```

Then I put it into a pickle file and open it as the following:

```
df_fire ={}
account, pwd = 'E', 'I!'
for var, query in query_dict.items():
    df_fire[var] = get_SQL_raw_data(account, pwd, var, query)

pickle.dump(df_fire, open('./input/df_fire.pkl', 'wb'))

df_fire_dict = pickle.load(open('./input/df_fire.pkl', 'rb'))
df_fire = df_fire_dict['df_fire']
```

However, this result is only for 201801 without snap date. My goal is to make a dataframe with yyyymm from 201801 to 202004 (showing as the following). That is, I want to count how many insurance policy a person has in each month. Maybe I need to use for loop but I couldn't figure out where and how to use it.

```
My goal:

yyyymm icust_d cnt
-------------------
201801 A12345   1
201802 A12345   1
201803 A12345   2
....    ....   ....
202004 A12345   5
```

I'm new to Python and have been gooling how to do this for hours but still can't get it done. Hope someone can help. Thank you very much.

Comment: That is interesting your SQL did not error out in Oracle with missing `GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Parfait  Oh...I accidentally deleted that group by query when I was deleting some sensitive information. Thank you for reminding me this. I've edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an extended aggregate query to group on `YYYYMM`. No loop needed:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(POLICY_EFFDATE, 'YYYYMM') AS YYYYMM, 
       INSURED_ID AS CUST_ID, 
       COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM POLICY
WHERE POLICY_EXPDATE >= TO_DATE('2018/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
  AND POLICY_EFFDATE <= TO_DATE('2020/04/30', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(POLICY_EFFDATE, 'YYYYMM'), 
         INSURED_ID
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(POLICY_EFFDATE, 'YYYYMM')
```